# How to prevent keyboard from popping up when using dateInput on mobile?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a R Shiny app. It works great on a PC. When I run it on my iPhone and use the dateInput, it causes a slight 'zoom in' on the map, and it also brings up the keyboard. Neither of these are desired.

I had a similar problem with selectInput on iPhone apps, but was able to fix it with the 'selectize = FALSE' option in the selectInput call.

I can not seem to find some similarly simple way (or any way) to prevent this behavior with dateInput.

I have read several different 'similar' questions on here, but not of the offered solutions seem exactly relevant, and they did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following line I found to be necessary to prevent the 'zooming' that would occur when the user used `dateInput`:

```
tags$head(
    tags$meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no")
)
```

Note that I found I needed to use this add attributes approach to prevent the keyboard from popping up for `dateInput` on the mobile app:

```
tagAppendAttributes(
    DateInput("date1", "Date:", value=Sys.Date(), max=Sys.Date(), min="2022-10-01", autoclose=TRUE),
    readonly="",
    .cssSelector="input"
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).